iOS App not running in Background when downloaded from Testflight. But will run perfectly when installed from Xcode directly to device
In Xcode I have added Background mode capabilities, Because of which I am able to execute code in Background.
How I validate this
I checked this through scheduling NSTimer to print logs. Timer is printing logs perfectly with Application state as UIApplication.State.background, When installed on the device through Xcode.
But when the same app is uploaded to Test flight and installed on the device. Timer is only able to log Active and InActive State but not able to log UIApplication.State.background.
Hence my app is not running in background when installed from Test flight.
Can Anyone help me out with this bug or missing checks. Attaching the image of my capabilites and info plist  

Background is never guaranteed and Timer is known to not survive background. You have to find a different approach.

Hey Background is never guaranteed when you look for background task identifer, then in that case its depend on iOS whether it grant you or not.
But through background modes its guarnteed as I have test this in my build installed directly through Xcode.

I’m sure you were is DEBUG mode and that is why it was working. There are many reasons why something works when installed from Xcode and not production.

What are you doing in the background? You're declaring multiple unrelated background modes (which will get you rejected if you're abusing any of these btw), so it's hard to tell how iOS is supposed to grant you background privileges. How are you triggering the background execution? Is it via a background task? Incoming VOIP call? You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Apps behave differently when installed/running via Xcode to when they are installed  via Testflight/appstore. But what are you expecting those background modes to do anyway? I get the impression you think adding them will mean your app will constantly run in the background, no it won't, they don't work like that.

Sorry for the less information I had provided. Actually I am creating an app for Joining Audio/Video Meetings using Webrtc, Which is working fine when app is running in foreground/Active state.
I am able to properly join and share my video and audio with other person inside the meeting. But when app moves to background My Socket connection to webrtc server breaks due to which app stops working, not able to send and listen audio in background.

@Piepants To identify what is the issue, and Why my socket connection get disconnected in Background.  I have started a timer to log the application state after only this I am able to figure out Testflight App is not working in background.
